# R言語におけるデータフレームから欠損値を除去する方法、欠損値しかない列の除去（もしくは0への変換）

Tags: r

たびたび初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
下記質問では大変お世話になりました。
[R言語におけるMann Whitney Test （もしくはt-test）の計算結果の出力する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36105/r%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8Bmann-whitney-test-%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AFt-test-%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%AE%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

今度は下記のようなデータの取り扱いについて、ご教授お願い出来ないでしょうか。

```
       A1 A2 A3 A4
       31       54
       56    48 69
       11    13 14
       16    18 
             63 24
             28 22
       31    33 31
       36    78 31
       41    43 41
```

とあるデータの大元の測定器からの出力が上記のようなexcelファイルであり、これまではexcelを使って空欄を削除し、上に詰めていました。

```
       A1 A2 A3 A4
       31    48 54
       56    13 69
       11    18 14
       16    63 24
       31    28 22
       36    33 31
       41    78 31
             43 41
```

このようなデータを`wilcox.exact`で実行すると、A2列に数字がないため（全てNA)にエラーがでました。そこで`Data <- Data[ ,is.na(Data[1,]) == FALSE]`で1行目に数値データがないものを削除したのですが、列がずれると後々面倒かと思い、`Data[ ,is.na(Data[1,])] <- 0`にて、1行目に数値データがない列のNAを全部0にしてみました。（そもそもこの列にデータが無いことは図により認識できるので、とにかく`wilcox.exact`が動けば良しです。）

しかし、excelでの処理を簡素化できないかと思い、

```
       A1 A2 A3 A4
       31       54
       56    48 69
       11    13 14
       16    18 
             63 24
             28 22
       31    33 31
       36    78 31
       41    43 41
```

上記のデータのまま、下記の処理ができないかと考えています。
・列の値がNAしかないのものはNAを0にする。
・その他の場合はNAを削除し、上に詰める。

NAを全て0にした場合、演算結果に影響がでるのでは考えていますが、NAを0にする方法も教えていただければ幸いです。

ご指導のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

まず，矩形でないデータはdata.frameにはできません。なのでNAを詰めて使うならば，

1. list型として利用，あるいはそれぞれをベクトルで切り離して利用
2. long data(縦型データ)へ変換して利用

のいずれかとなります。以降は後者を念頭においています:

```
library(tidyr)

# サンプル用のデータ生成
df <- data.frame(
  A1 = sample(c(4:6, NA), 10, prob = c(4, 2, 2, 2), replace = TRUE),
  A2 = rep(NA, 10),
  A3 = sample(c(4:6, NA), 10, prob = c(2, 4, 2, 2), replace = TRUE),
  A4 = sample(c(4:6, NA), 10, prob = c(2, 2, 4, 2), replace = TRUE)
)

# サンプル用データの構造を確認
str(df)
  #>  'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
  #>   $ A1: int  6 5 NA 4 6 5 5 4 5 NA
  #>   $ A2: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  #>   $ A3: int  5 6 5 5 6 5 NA NA 5 4
  #>   $ A4: int  6 6 NA 4 6 5 6 6 4 6

# long data(縦型データ)へ変換
# tidyr::gather関数を使ってます
df_long <- gather(df, key = fac, value = value, factor_key = TRUE)
str(df_long)
  #>  'data.frame': 40 obs. of  2 variables:
  #>   $ fac  : Factor w/ 4 levels "A1","A2","A3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  #>   $ value: int  6 5 NA 4 6 5 5 4 5 NA ...

# valueの列でNAがあるものを除去
# tidyr::drop_na関数を使ってます
df_long_rmNA <- drop_na(df_long, value)
str(df_long_rmNA)
  #>  'data.frame': 25 obs. of  2 variables:
  #>   $ fac  : Factor w/ 4 levels "A1","A2","A3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 ...
  #>   $ value: int  6 5 4 6 5 5 4 5 5 6 ...

# NAを別の値へ置換
# tidyr::replace_na関数を使ってます
df_long_repNA <- replace_na(df_long, list(value = 0))
str(df_long_repNA)
  #>  'data.frame': 40 obs. of  2 variables:
  #>   $ fac  : Factor w/ 4 levels "A1","A2","A3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  #>   $ value: num  6 5 0 4 6 5 5 4 5 0 ...
```

おそらくはこれで希望されたデータの加工ができるかと思います。なお，この縦型データのままで`wilcox.exact`も実行可能です:

```
library(exactRankTests)
  #>   Package 'exactRankTests' is no longer under development.
  #>   Please consider using package 'coin' instead.

# wilcox.exact関数を実行(fomula形式で指定)
# 引数subsetで，用いるレコード(行)を絞る
# subsetの使い方についてはsubset関数を参照
wilcox.exact(value ~ fac, df_long,
             subset = df_long$fac %in% c("A1", "A3"))
  #>  
  #>    Exact Wilcoxon rank sum test
  #>  
  #>  data:  value by fac
  #>  W = 29, p-value = 0.9776
  #>  alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
wilcox.exact(value ~ fac, df_long_rmNA,
             subset = df_long_rmNA$fac %in% c("A1", "A3"))
  #>  
  #>    Exact Wilcoxon rank sum test
  #>  
  #>  data:  value by fac
  #>  W = 29, p-value = 0.9776
  #>  alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
wilcox.exact(value ~ fac, df_long_repNA,
             subset = df_long_repNA$fac %in% c("A1", "A3"))
  #>  
  #>    Exact Wilcoxon rank sum test
  #>  
  #>  data:  value by fac
  #>  W = 47, p-value = 0.9131
  #>  alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

ただ，exactRankTestsパッケージはまもなく開発完了するのでcoinパッケージを使うように，とメッセージがでました。一応coinパッケージのwilcox_test関数を利用したバージョンも以下に示します:

```
library(coin)
  #>  Loading required package: survival
  #>  
  #>  Attaching package: 'coin'
  #>  The following objects are masked from 'package:exactRankTests':
  #>  
  #>      dperm, pperm, qperm, rperm
wilcox_test(value ~ fac, df_long,
            subset = df_long$fac %in% c("A1", "A3"),
            distribution = "exact")
  #>  
  #>    Exact Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
  #>  
  #>  data:  value by fac (A1, A3)
  #>  Z = -0.35161, p-value = 0.9776
  #>  alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

出力もつけたほうがわかりやすいかと思ったのですが，長文となり申し訳ありません。